# Flow with Fault handling does not rollback all DMLs?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a Flow that creates several types of records:  Contract, Order and Order Products.
Initially if the Flow encountered any errors on the DML elements it would report the ugly "Unexpected Fault" error screen and no data would be created.
I added screens to handle "Fault" outcomes for the DML elements which worked well however if the fault occurred in later part of the Flow - for example when Order Products are inserted the previously inserted Contract and Order remained.

This is not ideal!
Has anyone found a method to make sure the Flow does not create/update any data if there is a DML error that is handled by a fault message?

Comment: If possible you can try putting all the create and update elements after your last screen. That should make sure all the dml operations are in the same context, and are rolled back together if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read your question as well as i should have. Try making sure that the faults are never reached by checking for the conditions that cause the faults before the element that creates the fault. You can than do whatever is necessary to make sure that either no data is saved, or the error is handled by the user in the flow. (Btw, in flows all the data manipulation actions are committed before a screen is reached, so this is normal behavior. )

Answer (score 0):

Quick update to this post - in Winter 22, a [Roll Back](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_roll_back_records.htm&release=234&type=5) element was added to flow for this use case

> Roll Back Pending Record Changes When a Flow Element Fails at Run Time
> To roll back a transaction and cancel all its pending record changes
> in a screen flow, add the new Roll Back Records element in a fault
> path. Previously, when a transaction ended, its pending record changes
> were saved to the database even if a flow element failed in the
> transaction.